# How to add/update articles easily on Wikipedia?

Tags: automation, mediawiki

To create files for Wikipedia, I use a combination of software (Vim, Markdown, Pandoc, Git ...). As a developer this is just how I'm comfortable.

My problem is that to add or update (especially the latter which is particularly cumbersome) an article, I need to do it manually. Is there a way to fully automatize this process?
I want something like `push`ing modifications to a repository?

---

**EDIT**
This how I how I want my workflow to look like :

1. Fetching article to VIM
2. Edit it using Markdown
3. Convert file to MediaWiki format using Pandoc
4. Submit article from Vim or console (I use Cygwin)

My problem is with steps 1. and 4. Any help?

Comment: Can you be more specific? To add or edit an article on wikipedia easily, you can use the interface on the web site.

Comment: Good point. Question updated :)

Comment: If you're updating so many Wikipedia articles that the actual update operation is a bottleneck, one might be tempted to suspect that you're spamming.

Comment: Lol. Seems ligit but no. I and other enthusiasts are trying to launch Wikipedia in our local language (it's in Wikipedia's projects incubator right now). Of course, there are a lot of things to write about and automatizing as much as possible is key to success :)

Answer (score 2):

Approaches that I used in the past:

1. [It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/), a Firefox addon that allows you to open any text box on any webpage (which includes the Wikipedia page edit box) in your favorite text editor. When you save the file and close the editor, the text box will be updated with the changes you made in the text editor.
2. [AutoWikiBroswer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:AutoWikiBrowser), an application that simplifies editing of some group of pages. For example, you can easily add a category or use search-and-replace on those pages.
3. [Write a bot.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Creating_a_bot) This is the most general option and also by far the most difficult, since it requires you to know programming.

Comment: I'm afraid I'll have to write my own bot :/

Comment: @ahmed You might also try [Wikipedia:Bot requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bot_requests) at the English Wikipedia to find someone to write that bot for you or help you with it. It's meant for bots for the English Wikipedia, but it's possible someone there will be willing to help you.